# react native creating object with arrays

Tags: javascript

i have arrays like this:

```js
[
0: {barcode: '4124121241241', qty: 1}
1: {barcode: '1234124135134', qty: 1}
2: {barcode: '3573424625234', qty: 1}
3: {barcode: '2346468457354', qty: 1}
4: {barcode: '5684452043432', qty: 1}
5: {barcode: '1241263475686', qty: 5}
6: {barcode: '1231241231423', qty: 15}
]
```

and i'm pushing those like this:

```js
shelfArray.push({
    [rafName]:JSON.parse(results.rows.item(index).BarcodeArray)
});
```

this is my output:

```js
0:
Q1:
BarcodeArray: [{…}]
1:
Q2:
BarcodeArray: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2: {Q3: null}
```

but i want this like :

```js
Q1:
BarcodeArray: [{…}]
Q2:
BarcodeArray: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2: {Q3: null}
```

how can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating `shelfArray` as an array `[]`, create it as an empty object

```
const shelfArray = {}; // rather than `= [];`
```

and then add keys to that object as you loop instead of
pushing by using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation):

```js
shelfArray[rafName] = JSON.parse(results.rows.item(index).BarcodeArray);
```